# Trigger SlideToggle Programmatically Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having trouble initially hiding my toolbar when a page is loaded. I want the navbar to initially start off in a closed state. The code I am using toggle between open and closed states is here..

```
$("div[data-role=header]").on("click", function () {
    $("div[data-role=navbar]").slideToggle(200);
});

$("div[data-role=navbar]").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This code does exactly what I want but I cannot figure out what I can do have the navbar start out in a closed state when the page initially loads

http://jsfiddle.net/DMUwp/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "closed" state with regards to slideToggling is one in which the css display value is set to none.

```
#nav { display: none; }
```